# Importing JavaFlacEncoder from Maven

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I'm trying to load the JFE library from [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.javaflacencoder/java-flac-encoder/0.3.7) but when I build my gradle project it's throwing symbol errors. In my IDE as well, I'm getting unrecognised symbol errors.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6CPf.png)

I've tried using both:

```
compile group: 'net.sourceforge.javaflacencoder', name: 'java-flac-encoder', version: '0.3.7'
```

and

```
implementation 'net.sourceforge.javaflacencoder:java-flac-encoder:0.3.7'
```

I tried downloading the latest version available on the source forge and adding it as a dependency using my IDE (IntelliJ). This worked, but when I built it because it's a raw jar dependency, instead of a gradle dependency, the gradle build fails.

I want my project to be portable, so I want it to rely on gradle dependencies instead of jar dependencies. Why is this gradle dependency not working?